# tinyMCE-Angular and the code plugin - binding to events in modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, tinymce

Angular 7, using tinyMCE-angular, and we've configured it to use the 'code' plugin. That plugin (in our case) inserts a button [< >] into the tinymce toolbar.  [image: the button]

When you click that button, a modal opens.
[image: the modal]

The problem I have is that we have an (onKeyUp) event triggering when the content of the main tinymce editor is edited--but it doesn't trigger when the code modal is used, because that modal inserts content without using an (onKeyUp) event.

The HTML:

```
<editor [init]="tinyMceSettings" apiKey="{{tinyMceApiKey}}" id="_featureTabContent" [(ngModel)]="marketPlaceModel.featureContent"
                  (onKeyUp)="onEditorKeyUp('Features_Tab')"></editor>
```

The Component code, which is enabling a 'Preview' button below the tinymce editor to either be enabled or disabled.

```
  onEditorKeyUp(str) {
    if (this.marketPlaceModel.featureContent != null && this.marketPlaceModel.featureContent.length != 0) {
      this.disablePreviewBtns.featuresbtn = false;
      this.marketPlaceModel.featureTabValVisbile = false;
    }
    else {
      this.disablePreviewBtns.featuresbtn = true;
      this.marketPlaceModel.featureTabValVisbile = true;
    }
```

tinyMCE has event triggers (https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-angular#event-binding), I'm assuming I can use those events somehow (like we're using the onKeyUp event currently) to trigger the same `onEditorKeyUp()` event, but I can't seem to get that to work. 
Is there some way to do this that is built into the tinymce editor already, and I'm just missing it?

Comment: Why do you want to get it if that content in modal is not saved until you click on Ok button?

Comment: I may just need to watch the 'OK' button. The key thing is, when they enter content into the modal, when they click OK, that content is 'inserted' into the tinymce editor (it is already doing that) but that the 'Preview' button is enabled using that onEditorKeyUp() method. I may not need it to trigger on X or Cancel in that case.

Answer (score 0):

OK so we ended up fixing this, doing the following:

```
<editor [init]="tinyMceSettings" apiKey="{{tinyMceApiKey}}" id="_featureTabContent" [(ngModel)]="marketPlaceModel.featureContent"
                  (onKeyUp)="onEditorKeyUp('Features_Tab')" (onDirty)="onEditorKeyUp('Features_Tab')"></editor>
```

Adding the `onDirty` call successfully updates the button when the class is changed from ng-pristine to ng-dirty. However, if you then remove all of the content, it does not re-update the field until the button is clicked. To fix that, we updated the method:

```
  onEditorKeyUp(str) {
    if (this.marketPlaceModel.featureContent != null && this.marketPlaceModel.featureContent.length != 0) {
      this.ref.detectChanges();
      this.disablePreviewBtns.featuresbtn = false;
      this.marketPlaceModel.featureTabValVisbile = false;
    }
    else {
      this.disablePreviewBtns.featuresbtn = true;
      this.marketPlaceModel.featureTabValVisbile = true;
    }
```

That fixed the issue for us.